# Is this good way of using .NET's System.Lazy

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading

```
    private Lazy<Image> _headshot = new Lazy<Image>(LoadHeadshotFromHDD);

    public Image Headshot
    {
        get
        {
            return _headshot.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _headshot = new Lazy<Image>(() => value);
        }
    }
```

Let's say I have a `Person` class and `Headshot` property is in that class. `Headshot` is loaded from HDD so I want it to be lazy, but I also want to implement setter for that property. Will there be a problem with the way that I've implemented this? I'm just not sure that I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Why would you want to be completely lazy? If loading it takes significant time, you don't want to do that in the middle of a frame when you first use it. You probably don't want to do load everything serially at start up, but this is hardly better. A more common and useful strategy is to load concurrently before you need it (only stalling if you really can't keep up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really no point in using lazy loading if you already have the object in memory (in the setter case), but it's perfectly fine to do it this way. One thing I can think of, is if you'd check the `_headshot.IsValueCreated`, it'll return false, even though you already have the object in memory. Another alternative would be

```
private Image _headshot;

public Image Headshot
{
    get { return _headshot ?? (_headshot = LoadHeadshotFromHDD()); }
    set { _headshot = value; }
}
```

This will lazy load the headshot when the property is accessed, just like when using `Lazy<T>`, but it'll set the value directly, so you can check `_headshot != null` instead of `_headshot.IsValueCreated`. You should check out Jon Skeet's [Singleton Pattern post](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: That's the way to go.

Comment: Alternative method would not work in all cases - let's say that null is a valid value. If Headshot is set to null and then read some later time, this method would return data from the HDD instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok, however, if you'd take the initialization to the constructor, you could have less code.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.Headshot = new Lazy<Image>( () => LoadHeadshotFromHDD );
    }

    public Lazy<Image> Headshot { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I wanted. I think that property should be of Image type, not Lazy<Image>. If property's type is Lazy<Image>, then you can't simple assign it an Image - each time you must create Lazy instance.

Comment: No problem, it is your design decision.